# changing a string 'recursively' in PHP

Tags: php, string, switch-statement

I want to change a string (in PHP) using several conditionals to define which change should be made, update the string and keep changing the updated string.

For example, start with a string and based on a condition, make a change in the character, then use the second version of the string, and based on another condition, change it some more, and so on, in such a way that at the end of the process, the changes have been cumulative.

Apparently, variable scope prevents the following approach:

```
$newstring = "This is a test string";
$value[] // This is an array already defined.

 for ($i = 0; $i<=count($value); $i++) {
    switch ($value[$i]) {
     case -1:
      $newstring = preg_replace(// do something with $newstring);
      break;
    case 0:
      $newstring = preg_replace ( // do something else with $newstring);
      break;
    case 1:
      $newstring = substr_replace(//do something else with $newstring);
      break;
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Here is my code. As you can expect, `$_POST['text1']` is a string and `$_POST['array']` is a two dimensional array.

```
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$value = $_POST['array'];

for ($i = 0; $i<=count($value); $i++) {
 switch ($value[$i][0]) {


    case -1:
       $newstring = preg_replace("/".$value[$i][1]."/","",$text1,1);
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        $newstring = substr_replace($text1, $value[$i][1],$value[$i][2],0);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get?  How do you know it is related to variable scope?

Comment: I think you meant //do something with $newstring.. I don't think it's a variable scope problem..

Comment: @Jeremiah: Well, I don't get an error. I get the last change made by the switch statement, which is only one change instead of several changes applied to the string.

Comment: @amitchd: Right. Last minute change. I will correct it.

Comment: @Robert: Like @amitchd is saying, are you sure you are using `$newstring` as input rather than `$string` in each of the replacements?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Yes, absolutely. It was a typo :-).

Comment: @Robert: I see the new code.  A couple quick things to be sure of: Are you sure all of the elements of `$value` are in range?  Are you sure your regexes are matching?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Thanks for your interest. Yes, no problem there. I made the changes I want to enforce 'manually' and the result is correct, that is, only the last change survives in $newstring. Of course, that's not the intended behavior.

Comment: @Robert: I don't understand your last comment fully.  If you do the changes manually, is what comes out correct or incorrect (according to what you want the code to do)?

Comment: @Robert: Maybe if you paste a code which gives us a clearer example would help i.e. with the regex instead of the comment. It's not a variable scope problem for sure!

Comment: @Jeremiah: Oh, alright. I know what changes are to be made, right?. They are like "remove the fifth character" or "add x letter". Therefore, given a small number of changes, I can make them manually. For example, in one set of changes, the result should be "Hello". Instead, I got "llo". That's because only the last change was made.

Comment: @Robert: So when you made the changes manually, you got the wrong answer?  Or are you saying when you did them manually, you got the right answer, but the code didn't?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Right, I got an incorrect answer. The same answer I would get if only the last change (in the loop) was made.

Comment: @amitchd: Alright, I will paste the code in a minute.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Oh, sorry. I got confused in the comments. Let me correct my answer. When I make the changes *manually* I get the correct answer. When a run the code, I get the incorrect answer :-).

Comment: @Robert: That makes more sense.

Comment: @Robert: Seeing your code, you are not working on `$newstring`, so you are never using the results of the previous loop iterations.  See @amitchd's comment at the beginning of the thread.

Comment: @Robert: I just posted an answer now that I see in the code what the problem is.

Comment: @Jeremiah: No, the update was intended to show my code. In the first part, I made up some variable to abstract the problem a little bit (as I thought the problem was the scope). Therefore, the first quote and the second are not really related.

Comment: @Robert: If your second code example is the one you are using, the problem is that you are not using `$newstring`, independently of what the first code example does.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Do you mean I should replace $text1 for $newstring?. Is not that weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your changes to newstring, by replacing text on text1 everytime. You need to preserve those changes by using newstring everywhere.

```
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$value = $_POST['array'];
$newstring = $text1;
for ($i = 0; $i<=count($value); $i++) {
 switch ($value[$i][0]) {


    case -1:
       $newstring = preg_replace("/".$value[$i][1]."/","",$newstring,1);
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        $newstring = substr_replace($newstring, $value[$i][1],$value[$i][2],0);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice. It worked!. Only a minor error "Undefined offset in line 9" (the switch line).

Comment: Oh, that error appeared because $i<=count($value) was calling a non existent index. Jeremiah was right about that.